# What does 「で」mean in 「試合で 失敗しました」? Why not use 「に」?

Tags: particles, particle-で, に-and-で

I just did the listening Mondai 2 for Lesson 33 of Minna No Nihongo 2 (the older ver.).
And in question 5, it says「山田君は 今の試合**で** 失敗しましたが、次の試合で 頑張ります。」

I've learned that you use 「に」before 「失敗する」, and I don't know why it uses 「で」here instead.

What does「で」mean here? And how do I know when to use 「で」or「に」？

Comment: How did you understand this sentence (in English, for example)?

Comment: I think it means he failed this game. I'm thinking maybe with the で　here it refers to where the action happened, so it means more like "In this game, he failed." But the textbook mentions that you use 「に」before 失敗します (e.g. 試験に失敗します). I wonder if there's any difference between using に and で here? And how do I know when to use which?

Comment: Aha, as I suspected. That's right, that it doesn't mean "failed the game".

Answer (score 5):

X **に**失敗する means "fail to X" or "fail to achieve success in X", in other words, your objective is met with failure trying to do X. Otherwise, it just means intransitive *fail*, or "make a failure". で is just there to indicate the circumstance.

> × 試験に失敗したが、合格することができた
> *I failed the exam, but I was able to pass it.* (contradictory)
>
> ○ 試験で失敗したが、合格することができた
> *I made a mistake in the exam, but I was able to pass it.*

> 山田君は今の試合で失敗しましたが、次の試合で頑張ります。
> *Yamada made a failure in this game, but will try his best in the next.*